# working with missing data in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have a time series data frame with x and y as columns name. In my dataframe y is incomplete series and x is complete series. I tried to fit linear regression model between x and y. My intetion is to fill data gap by usig this model. my sample codes are:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
result = sm.ols(formula="y ~ x", data=df_rg).fit()
df_rg['y'][df_rg['y'].fillna(predict(df_rg['x'])
```

where df_rg is my dataframe with datetime as an index.

my dataframe looks like:

```
date         x          y
1957-07-31  18.845161   NaN
1957-08-31  18.080645   NaN
1957-09-30  16.156667   NaN
1957-10-31  12.324194   NaN
1957-11-30  8.948333    NaN
1957-12-31  6.253226    NaN
.............................
.............................
2015-03-31  8.316129    20.088710
2015-04-30  10.408333   22.203333
2015-05-31  14.832258   25.258065
2015-06-30  16.815000   26.453333
2015-07-31  18.141935   26.835484
2015-08-31  18.450000   26.637097
2015-09-30  17.016667   26.513333
2015-10-31  11.898387   22.906452
2015-11-30  9.133333    19.376667
2015-12-31  5.366129    14.441935
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use the dataframe without the NA values for the fitting, using [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)?

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
result = sm.ols(formula="y ~ x", data=df_rg.dropna()).fit()
df_rg['y'] = df_rg['y'].fillna(predict(df_rg['x']))
```

Comment: @bikuser did you assign it back ? df_rg['y']=df_rg['y'][df_rg['y'].fillna(predict(df_rg['x'])

Comment: @bikuser I guess ther was an `=` sign missing to assign it back as said above. Also, you were missing a `)`.

Comment: @wen, Graipher cannot reindex from a duplicate axis i got this message

Comment: @bikuser df_rg['y']=df_rg['y'][df_rg['y'].fillna(predict(df_rg['x'])).values

Comment: @Wen unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @Graipher now it working maybe I did mistake earlier thank you so much :)